# Primary key on isolated table

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I cannot really find a solution to my problem and the question is: do I really have to create a primary key here?

---

**Details**

My website has a table in a database called `translations` in which I put each single sentence/word with different translations. I have this structure:

```
id  | lang | text
-------------------
01  |  01  | hello
01  |  02  | ciao
01  |  03  | salut
02  |  01  | surname
02  |  02  | cognome
02  |  03  | nom
```

The field `id` is connected to a word, the field `lang` is a number that indicates the translation (01 = english, 02 = italian, 03 = french) and the `text` is the translation of that word.

In this case, if I need (for example) the word *hello* I know that it has id = 1 and then I can choose the language.

Is this a good way to create this kind of table? I am not sure but I find this easy because I can call:

```
SELECT text FROM tablename WHERE id = ? AND lang = ?
```

You can see the ? because I bind params with PDO. The 'lang' is a constant retrieved form a cookie (01,02,03).

**Important note:** here I have no primary keys, I have only set `id` and `lang` to unique

Comment: If you have a unique index, you should make that a primary key.  I think you're confusing _primary key_ with _surrogate key_.  Look up both terms.  Also, you can read an answer to this question on DBA.SE: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6108/should-every-table-have-a-single-field-surrogate-artificial-primary-key/6110#6110

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep your table structure and you have just **one** translation per language for each word, then you can use `id` + `lang` as primary key

```
CREATE TABLE translations
(
   id int,
   lang int,
   text varchar(150) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id, lang) 
);
```